# What is this Soviet Russian game featuring a complex path on a black background?

Tags: identify-this-game

A Russian friend found this game from his grandmother, but doesn't have the name or any other details. A reverse image search didn't turn anything up. What is it?

[image: Game Board]

Comment: A close-up & translation of the "spaces colour/symbol key" (to the right of the round pic) would help.  Also, if the pic is of Lenin (l.) & Trotsky (r.) then this game would be dated 1923-1925 (the only post-Revolution time Trotsky would be wearing an uniform...assuming games re: the Revolution wouldn't be made until it succeeded 1918-1925 if they "felt lucky").  Trotsky fell "out-of-favour" in late 1925-early 1926 and wouldn't be featured in a game afterward.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a dice game. The rules of the game are indicated on the game itself: you need to play a two or more, throw a dice and move according to the fallen number

Comment: Would you be able to provide a translation to the text on the board?

Comment: More info would be useful for the OP, you don't provide much detail.